# why mysql timestamp column use timestamp to search get larger result?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

`select count(*) from PN_Review where addTime >= '2017-05-01 00:00:00';`
result:3468

`select count(*) from PN_Review where addTime >= 1493568000;`
result:37645  which is exactly larger than fact.

addTime column is created by timestamp

what I do wrong with second query?

Comment: Have you tried performing the result on the first query again? did you get the same result?

Comment: Add `MIN(addTime)` to the SELECT list, and you will see different values returned. That second query is *not* equivalent to the first, it's doing something quite different, and probably *not* what you want.

Comment: ``select count(*),min(addTime) from PN_Review where addTime >= 1493568000;``  get ``37685 2016-04-27 19:15:03``   and user ``addTime`` to replace ``min(addTime)``get the same time. I almost know what happened!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's happening with that second query.

MySQL to accessing every row in the table, and converting the value in the `addTime` (TIMESTAMP) column into a string value. And then comparing the string value to a literal `'1493568000'.

```
    addTime >= 1493568000
```

that's essentially the same as specifying `

```
    addTime >= '1493568000'
```

which is equivalent to

```
    DATE_FORMAT(addTime,'%Y-%m-%d %T) >= '1493568000'
```

All of those will evaluate to TRUE for an addTime value of `'1970-01-02'`, and for any non-NULL value other than '0000-00-00'. And MySQL has to perform that conversion and comparison for every row in the table.

Consider adding `MIN(addTime)` to the SELECT list, along with the `COUNT(*)`, and I expect the value returned will differ from the value returned by the first query.

---

With the expression in the first query:

```
    addTime >= '2017-05-01 00:00:00'
```

MySQL evaluates the literal string on the right side as a datetime value in the current timezone, and then compares that to the value of `addTime` TIMESTAMP column. (With this form, MySQL can make use of an index (with `addTime` as the leading column) to perform a range scan operation.)

---

Here are some other forms to consider:

```
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(addTime) >= 1493568000
```

The `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function will return the internal integer "seconds" value from the TIMESTAMP,and compare that to the numeric literal.

```
    addTime >= FROM_UNIXTIME(1493568000)
```

The value returned by the `FROM_UNIXTIME` function is influenced by the setting of the session `time_zone` variable. The returned value is compared to the TIMESTAMP column.

Consider this demonstration:

```
    SET time_zone = '+05:00' ;
    SELECT @@time_zone, FROM_UNIXTIME(1493568000) ;
```

returns

```
    @@time_zone  FROM_UNIXTIME(1493568000) 
    -----------  -------------------------
    +05:00       2017-04-30 21:00:00
```

compare to

```
    SET time_zone = '+00:00' ;
    SELECT @@time_zone, FROM_UNIXTIME(1493568000) ;
```

which returns

```
    @@time_zone  FROM_UNIXTIME(1493568000)  
    -----------  -------------------------
    +00:00       2017-04-30 16:00:00
```

Comment: user ``select count(*) from PN_Review where addTime >= FROM_UNIXTIME(1493568000);  ``  can get right answer. thank you for your detail answer.